# is there an allowable alternative for a generator lockout? the configuration of my panel will not allow a lockout for the main and generator breaker

Tags: wiring

[image]My panel is a square D HOM. The main disconnect is located bottom center/left and throws to the left for ON. Directly above is the disconnect for the sub panel feeding the rear of the house and cannot be relocated due to the way the cabling is installed. The right side of the panel is only approx 30% occupied with the available space for the generator breaker at the top right. Can a modified main lockout for main only and a independent lockout ( clamp on with lock or a modified slide lockout) be used for generator disconnect?

Comment: A photo might be better, for explanation

Comment: Whatever you do must ensure that it is mechanically and electrically impossible to have a circuit connected to line and generator at the same time. You could have your electrician install a transfer switch upstream of the box. You can also reroute cabling, though that may not be less expensive. You can also put the transfer switch between main and subpanel and reroute all the "essential" circuits to come from the sub-panel.

Comment: Trick being, there's an actual listed and labeled part that requires using exactly and only that inlet location, and there are no other listed and labeled interlock parts for your panel, most especially including anything you home-brew or field-modify. Time to learn about Polaris connectors and move that subpanel feed.

Comment: Can you post photos of the panel in question please?

Comment: Thanks for all the info. It looks like splicing the subpanel cable and relocating that breaker is the only way the install the interlock and be in compliance of NEC 702

Comment: Check inside your subpanel to see if there is enough slack in those two hot subpanel feeders to slide them 2" or so toward the main.  If so, you can shift everything on the left side up two spaces without reterminating anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can find a UL-Listed generator interlock, go for it.  However third-party units may be more money; generally the cheapest are from the manufacturer.

### You will need to extend your feeder wires

and based on your photo, I would move the subpanel breaker high up on the right side, so nothing is across from it (or nothing larger than 15A breakers; that to minimize load on that bus stab which is shared by the opposite breaker).

To get there you will need to extend the existing feeder.  If you can identify the physical size of wire and metal, just buy exactly that. Otherwise go with #1 copper as you're only buying 4 feet and it'll be less of a fight to get it on the breaker.

To buy very short lengths of large wires, talk to an electrical supply house or a better lumberyard. Call around *by telephone* to find shops that sell it by-the-foot.  Feel free to have them cut it - 2 pieces of 2 feet each should get you there.

---

Choose **Polaris connectors** whose maximum size is the same size as your feeder wires - that will mean the insulation fits snug into the Polaris and doesn't leave gaps.  If you don't know the size, get 2/0 max.  The smaller the cheaper.

You will also need a torque wrench to set screw torques correctly on both the Polaris and the breaker.  This is a requirement.  Aluminum wire is proven reliable at these large sizes, and aluminum wire properly torqued is much safer than copper wire torqued to feel.  The Polaris lugs are made of aluminum, as is everything in the panel that is silver colored.

By the way if you have to extend your generator wires that are #6, use ILSCO Mac Block connectors or the really, really big wire nuts.

---

The inability to move breakers *is why* it is very bad to cut all wires as short as possible.  I know it makes the panel look "pretty", but then you can't maintain your panel.  Every wire should be long enough that hot and neutral can reach any space in the panel.  I think electricians do it to steal the copper they clipped :)

Also, hogging the spaces near the main breaker is dumb, because many specialty breakers *need* particular spaces - top of the list being a generator interlock breaker. SMH people think there'll be less resistance along the bus, I guess, but look at that bus - it's very wide with huge ampacity. There is less than 50 cents of aluminum in this whole panel, and everything shiny is aluminum. why not make the buses thick?

### Alternatives?

Even if you had to hire an electrician to fit and torque the Polaris connectors, still, that + Polaris + wire will still be far cheaper than any of your alternatives.

- a 200A whole-house transfer switch out at the meter
- a [meter-stacker](http://www.generlink.com/generlink.html) transfer switch
- a 6-8-10 circuit "per circuit" transfer switch such as Reliance, *which can only be installed in the main OR the sub, and cannot power the sub from the main*, so not very useful.  You cannot feed 2 transfer switches from 1 generator for technical reasons.

Comment: PIX posted as requested

Comment: @JImO'Dell Thanks but it doesn't change the answer.  If you can get a generator interlock for this panel that's very good. Alternatives are a 200A transfer switch out at the meter, or a 6/8/10 Reliance style per-circuit transfer switch EITHER here or at the subpanel.  Parts alone on either option will cost you *a heck of a lot more* than a couple Polaris connectors, a torque wrench, and the electrician's time to put them in.

Answer (score 3):

Your description matches a typical Square D Homeline main breaker and interlock setup. The more common configuration is the main breaker at the top and the interlock with the top right pair of breakers. You have the main breaker on the bottom, so the interlock is with the bottom left pair of breakers.

I find it unlikely (but not impossible) that you can't:

- Move the pair of breakers that are currently above the subpanel feed to another location.
- Move the subpanel feed up two spaces
- Install a generator feed in the old subpanel feed location so you can use a proper interlock.

Pictures of the panel with the deadfront (carefully) removed will show how the subpanel feed is connected. If it is coming from the bottom or the left with no excess wire available then you may be stuck, though even then it might be possible to splice with extension wires. If it is coming from the top or the right then this change should be trivial.

Comment: Splicing is definitely an option. A breaker box **is** a junction box, and a rather large one.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Agreed. The catch is the subpanel feed could be something like 2 AWG AL.

Comment: $32  will buy you a 3-port Polaris with a range from 5 AWG to 250 kcmils. Might well be a cheaper one that's just enough, rather than overkill, but that would certainly handle the job, easily, with no kooky illegal work.

Comment: 2 port 2awg ones are under $15/each.

Comment: Better to get one just big enough for the wires to be used. #1 why pay for more and #2 it fits the insulation jacket tightly so there is no exposed metal.